# php: how to reduce the cpu usage

Tags: php, cpu

I have a php web application running in a `Linode server(189G, 8G RAM)`.

A back end script is there for reading data from a big `xml file` and `inserting it into DB after processing`.

Also another script is there to `fetch this report from DB and to export into CSV`.

I have set the `memory_limit as 1GB for the application`, as it is reading large files.

And while running this script, in terminal it is showing CPU usage is high. I used top command while the script is running. there `'mysql'` user is showing more than `100/200 CPU usage`.

**What can be the reasons and how i can reduce this?**
What is the impact of memory_limit variable, machine specification, code loops in CPU usage?

Comment: Which version of PHP?

Comment: Without giving us the script, can you show us perhaps some pseudocode on what you are doing? Ultimately it comes down to code reuse and doing things inefficiently (which we really can't comment on).

Comment: PHP 5.6.4 and mysql 5.6.25

Comment: @Signus:script is somewhat big. and have multiple loops for processing. So Will the optimization of code and sql queries , reduce the CPU usage? or will the upgrading of server helps to fix it?

Comment: @santhy yes I would say you can look at it to see where optimization is possible. I would also say you don't want to limit `memory_limit` because you're working with large files - this actually hinders performance.

Comment: @Signus:So can i set -1 for ini memory_limit ?

Comment: first of all remove memory limit.second,check your code for recursions that may initiate Mysql connection multiple times, try using Single tone pattern for retrieving connection...these were my suggestions

Comment: Ok thank you all. Let me experiment..

Comment: I highly suggest adding pseudocode of some sort, otherwise this is nearly an open ended question. You'll get very common answers, but there are no specifics to work on other than PHP and MySQL version, your memory limiting - which really gives nobody anything to chew at.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to split the XML file into several files and see how that works.

Another solution would be to cap it's CPU usage with the **nice** or **cpulimit** command http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups

Comment: Capping CPU usage is fine if the OP doesn't mind the application being slower, for which the CPU is running high likely because it can't cache enough things into memory because he set `memory_limit = 1024` and mentioned he was working with large files.

Comment: Because his memory limit is smaller is why I suggested him to break it up into smaller files.

Comment: That would be ideal, but maybe the OP is grabbing these from another source and has little control over these. He may be able to try to use `fgets()` to help buffer these large files better.